# MVC5 - How to get results that span multiple entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Writing my first MVC app and using VS2013 and SQL Server 2008 R2, EF6 and a database first approach.

I have all the basics working for my app, but not sure how to approach this issue. I have a jobs table (JobID is PK) and an items table (with JobID as FK). There can be millions of items per job and I want a count of items displayed in the job record.

I can easily make a view or an SP to return a column with the item count, but I have many more examples like this and want to learn the correct way to do things like this in MVC apps

Not sure how best to accomplish this.

Could someone point me int he right direction?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: So you just want to get a count or related job items? That is pretty simple to do using EF and Count()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will count items in your navigation property:

```
var Quantity=db.Jobs.Items.Count();
```

This means items per job

Comment: Cool. thanks. Any implication wrt loading millions of items. I actually don;t want to load them at all, just get the count (if possible)

Comment: So does this go in my model in MVC?